# Error: The constructor SimpleAdapter is undefined... in listFragment

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello I have some trouble with the following code:

I have got a ListFragment, where I want set the content of  list "row" into "dataview" ... but when I want to do it the following error appears:

The constructor SimpleAdapter is undefined...

```
List<Data> row = db.getRow();
String[] from = { text1, text2};
int[] to = { R.id.text1_tv,R.id.text2_tv};
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), row , R.layout.dataview, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Do you see any mistake?

Comment: Well presumably there's no `SimpleAdapter` constructor that is suitable for the arguments you're passing. Which signature did you *expect* to call?

Comment: looks like the system cannot find your SimpleAdapter class. You either have not import the necessary file or you have not defined SimpleAdapter properly

Comment: Need more details on what you're passing to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), the [`SimpleAdapter`](http://javadox.com/com.google.android/android/4.0.1.2/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) constructor is:

```
SimpleAdapter(Context context,
    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
    int resource,
    String[] from,
    int[] to)
```

Are you sure that in your project `Data` extends `Map<String,?>` ?

A working example would be to have `row`  to be a `List<Map<String,String>>`

Comment: by definition of android, R.layout.dataview is an int.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a constructor like this :

```
SimpleAdapter(Activity activity, List<Data> row, DataView dataView, String[] from, int[] to){
// your code here
}
```

And replace the Activity and DataView with yours